# Error when building a project which uses ZipDiff and SharpLibZib

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, zip, nuget-package

I've been trying to use ZipDiff to compare two zip files. I installed ZipDiff through the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio which installed the necessary dependencies such "SharpZipLib" as well.

During the installation it was stated that the version of SharpZipLib has to be higher than or similar to 0.86 in order to use the latest version of ZipDiff. It was also mentioned that the SharpZipLib version which got downloaded was higher than 0.86. But when I tried to build the solution I get the following error.

Build error

[image: Build error]

Then when I checked the properties of the reference that was added, the version was "0.85..".

Properties Window

[image: Properties Window]

Then I reinstalled them and did it through the "Package Manager Console" but I got the same result.

Can someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Hi Panchali, what's your vs version and the project type? I tried to create a C# console application and install the package: ZipDiff.Core, check the reference 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib' and it's version is '0.86.0.518'. You can try to use the command: Update-Package under the Package Manager Console to update all packages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#using-update-package, then build it again. If this issue persists, could you please share the detail steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi Sara, my vs version is 2015 and the project type is a windows application. I tried using the command Update-Package but it was still the same.

Comment: Hi Panchali, thank you for your detail information, please have a try with this: Install-Package ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib -Version 0.86.0.518

Comment: If you create a new solution and install the package 'ZipDiff.Core', check the version of the reference 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib' , it is 0.86.xxx or 0.85.xxx.

Comment: It didn't work for me. But when I reinstalled Visual Studio and tried it, the error was gone. Thanks anyway!